# How to use MessagePack in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, messagepack

I read the [msgpack-cli quick start](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/wiki/Quick-Start) documentation.

I also got the C# (CLI) NuGet package (v0.3).

None of the classes (eg `BoxingPacker`, `CompiledPacker` or `ObjectPacker`) mentioned in the official documentation exist in the NuGet package (!!). I'm presuming the documentation has been orphaned.

So does anyone have examples how to serialize/deserialize  to/from MessagePack within C#? I'm trying to do this for an object and am interested in the binary nature of the serializer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To future readers: **I'd go with Avro or Protocol Buffers or even Thrift over MessagePack based on [these results](https://github.com/sidshetye/SerializersCompare#results) ...**

For the sake of the specific question, the key portions are:

```
public byte[] Serialize<T>(T thisObj)
{
    var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Create<T>();

    using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Pack(byteStream, thisObj);
        return byteStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] bytes)
{
    var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Create<T>();
    using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return serializer.Unpack(byteStream);
    }
}
```

The entire R&D type project, with results is at https://github.com/sidshetye/SerializersCompare and the specific function calls are [here](https://github.com/sidshetye/SerializersCompare/blob/master/SerializersCompare/Serializers/MessagePack.cs#L22).

Comment: Another option to consider: fastBinaryJSON (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345070/fastBinaryJSON)

Comment: 'MessagePackSerializer.Create<T>()' is Obsolete: 'Use Get<T>() instead.'

Comment: This is very old and needs an update. MessagePack smokes.

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised, nobody understood what the user asked. There are so many nuget packages for msgpack and it's really confusing which one to use and how to include in the projects. Im assuming the user wanted to know how to include msgpack in the .net project just like me.

```
Install MessagePack for CLI from Nuget packages
```

and then include like this

```
using MsgPack.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of [`msgpack-cli`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsgPack.Cli/) the `Create` method as in `MessagePackSerializer.Create<T>();` is marked as obsolete.

Example usage as given in the project's [github page](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli) may be:

```
// Creates serializer.
var serializer = SerializationContext.Default.GetSerializer<T>();
// Pack obj to stream.
serializer.Pack(stream, obj);
// Unpack from stream.
var unpackedObject = serializer.Unpack(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed in 10 years. MessagePack is fast and small, contrary to the accepted answer. We use [MessagePack-CSharp](https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp) library now.

You can see how it is faster and smaller than the old msgpack-cli here:

[image: MessagePack-CSharp speed and size chart]

It's easy to use.

Pack:

```
MyObjectType myObject = new();
byte[] packed = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

Unpack:

```
MyObjectType unPacked = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<MyObjectType>(packed);
```

Answer (score -1):

I find an example at:
http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/12/17/serializing-and-deserializing-packingunpacking-to-a-file-andor-memorystream-with-messagepack-in-c/
I test it in my code, and send the Byte[] data to another host by zmq. 
It works.

Answer (score -2):

Install the package named MsgPack from NuGet. See the pic here :

[image]